# t-sql How to use name column in patindex

Tags: t-sql, patindex

could you help me with such question:
I have such request

```
with a as  
(
    select 1 num, 21 q, 49 b,  100 scq, 155 o, '49 55;'  b_ost
    union
    select 2 num, 21 q, 50 b,  101 scq, 155 o,'50 54;49 55;'
    union
    select 3 num, 21 q, 48 b,  156 scq, 254 o, '48 98;50 54;49 55;'
    union
    select 4 num, 21 q, 49 b,  156 scq, 254 o,  '49 98;48 98;50 54;49 55;'
    union
    select 5 num, 21 q, 48 b,  150 scq, 254 o,   '48 104;49 98;48 98;50 54;49 55;'
)
select *  ,  PATINDEX('%48 %', b_ost), PATINDEX(b , b_ost)   from a
```

I need to find first position column b  in column  b_ost
If i use PATINDEX('%48 %', b_ost)  then position calculate right.
But i need to use column b instead of  '%48 %'  and if i will use PATINDEX(b , b_ost)   then position b into column b_ost will 0.
Solution through a variable is not suitable.
Please tell me how can I solve my issue?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood your requirements correctly, the code below will do it:

```
select * ,
       PATINDEX('%'+ CAST(b AS varchar)+'%', b_ost) from a
```

It always returns "1" with the sample data you kindly provided but I made a couple of changes to your sample and it works fine.

Comment: You dropped a space character after the numeric value. `+'%'` ought to be `+'% '`.

Comment: @HABO, are you sure about that? It returns 0 every time as `+'% '`.  `+' %'` does give valid results though.

Comment: My bad. The OP's original pattern was `'%48 %'`, so it was only matching the first in each pair of semicolon (`;`) delimited values, so the pattern should have `+' %'`. Their sample data doesn't have any interesting rows, i.e. ones where the match doesn't occur at the beginning of the string or where `b` is `42` and the string starts with `'42999 ...'`.